# Integrate g-suite (google) for signup and get user roles in desktop application

Tags: reactjs, electron, google-workspace

I am developing a desktop application using react electron boilerplate.
I need to integrate google signup, but it will not work since google providing the token in a redirect url.
Since it is a desktop application, I cannot fetch values from a url.

https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

How can I use google authentication and g-suite APIs in my app.

Help would be very much appreciated.